# Visual Basic Threading with More than 2 Threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am currently trying to produce a sound using a custom beep class.  One of the methods of the beep class is to produce multiple octaves of a sound with a given frequency, so one sound is the frequency, another is the frequency * 2, another is the frequency * 4, etc.

I am attempting to use threading to make these all sound together by giving each sound its own thread.  However, I notice that it still plays sounds once-at-a-time.  I can confirm that the sounds are not interrupting the flow of the program itself, however, so the threading is working in that capacity.

Here is the code I am using.  The idea is that for *NumOctave* times, a new frequency is generated based off the first (and amplitude), and is set to sound in its own thread.  However, it appears that the threads are queuing, rather than truly executing asynchronously from each other.  What would be the best way to get the intended behavior?

```
Shared Sub OctBeep(ByVal Amplitude As Integer,
         ByVal Frequency As Integer, ByVal NumOctaves As Integer,
         ByVal Duration As Integer, ByVal NewThread As Boolean)

    Dim threads As List(Of Thread) = New List(Of Thread)
    Dim powTwo As Integer = 1
    Dim powTen As Integer = 1
    For oct As Integer = 1 To NumOctaves
        Dim thisOct As Integer = oct

        Dim thisThread As New Thread(
              Sub()
                  Dim newFreq, newAmp As Integer
                  newFreq = Frequency * powTwo
                  newAmp = Amplitude / powTen
                  BeepHelp(newAmp, newFreq, Duration)
              End Sub
            )

        thisThread.IsBackground = True
        thisThread.Start()

        powTwo *= 2
        powTen *= 10
    Next

End Sub
```

Here is BeepHelp()

```
Shared Sub BeepHelp(ByVal Amplitude As Integer,
         ByVal Frequency As Integer,
         ByVal Duration As Integer)

    Dim A As Double = ((Amplitude * 2 ^ 15) / 1000) - 1
    Dim DeltaFT As Double = 2 * Math.PI * Frequency / 44100

    Dim Samples As Integer = 441 * Duration \ 10
    Dim Bytes As Integer = Samples * 4
    Dim Hdr() As Integer = {&H46464952, 36 + Bytes, &H45564157,
                            &H20746D66, 16, &H20001, 44100,
                             176400, &H100004, &H61746164, Bytes}
    Using MS As New MemoryStream(44 + Bytes)
        Using BW As New BinaryWriter(MS)
            For I As Integer = 0 To Hdr.Length - 1
                BW.Write(Hdr(I))
            Next
            For T As Integer = 0 To Samples - 1
                Dim Sample As Short = CShort(A * Math.Sin(DeltaFT * T))
                BW.Write(Sample)
                BW.Write(Sample)
            Next
            BW.Flush()
            MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            Using SP As New SoundPlayer(MS)
                SP.PlaySync()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: If you want to hear two at the same time, you'll need to combine them. It also depends on what BeepHelp does.

Comment: Good point about beepHelp, it plays a single beep without any threading.  The problem is, if I put both beeps in a single thread, they will happen one after another, not concurrently.

Comment: Hard to guess what BeepHelp() might do, but it is certainly consistent with the way beeps are generated.  Consider using the NAudio library to get ahead, it helps you synthesize wave forms.  Or something [like this](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Generating-Sound-Waves-with-C-Wave-Oscillators).

Comment: When you have a problem that you think multithreading might be the solution to you very often will end up with two problems.

Comment: I've just added beepHelp if you want to take a look, but I'll take a look at those other sound libraries as well.

Comment: Actually, I might want to use play instead of playsync.  Will try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue before writing a speech synthesizer class. There is a difference between Multi-threading(Just moves to a different thread so main program still works) & Parallel Processing(Moves the process to its own processor). You want to look into Parallel Processing instead